# Errors opening websocket client connections in Jakarta websocket 2.x against non-java servers

Tags: jakarta-websockets

I'd like to comment an issue I have migrating from javax.websocket to jakarta.websocket API 2.0 and 2.1.

The issue is that this Jakarta library fails to do the initial handshake under certain websocket servers. Library works fine with a local websocket server from the same API, however when I point the connection to a non java websocket server in LabView/C/C++ in Windows, it fails to establish the connection when I call `**ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().connectToServer(...)**`. The only output I got from the server is a handshake error and from the client side a TimeoutExecption.

The funniest part is that, exactly the same code, works with javax.websocket API under Java EE 8 and Java 11 but It does not work in Jakarta EE 10 and Java 17.
I moved away form Jakarta EE websocket packages and I jumped off into org.java-websocket and everything worked fine under Java 17.

Maybe ther is something I missed here, but just switching Java 11 to Java 17 and javax.websocket to jakakarta.websocket packages seems not work as it should.

Cheers and thank you